# Jquery $.get get method not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

```
<html>
      <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               var currenttime;
               function getDateInfo() { 
                 $.get("time.php?a=" + Math.random() , function(data) {
                   return data;
                  });

                }

                currenttime = getDateInfo();
                alert(currenttime);
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
/**************file time.php contains following code************/
<?php
    echo "August 27, 2011 19:30:52";
?>
```

Hello friends , please help why this code is not working..

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What errors have your received?

Comment: That isn't how it works.

Comment: To the downvoters: True, the OP could have asked it better; but if you take a moment to read the code, it is clear what the problem is - and it is an interesting problem by the way.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour the question as it exists now is unlikely to help anyone else in the future. Care to edit it?

Answer (score 2):

The `get` call is asynchronous. It returns to your code as soon as it has asked the browser to *start* the remote request. Your code then displays an alert without waiting for the request to complete -- so at that time there is of course no result yet.

This is why the function takes a callback argument instead of just returning the result. Your callback will be run long after `getDateInfo()` has returned, and you must arrange things such that actions that depend on the answer are started *by the callback function* rather than by the code that calls `$.get`.

Comment: Are you sure? I replaced `alert(currenttime);` with `setTimeout("alert(currenttime);",3000);` and the ajax call is taking 50 to 100 ms (so alert is fired after the result has arrived), but still the alert spits `undefined`. Why?

Comment: That's because the result is never stored in `currenttime`. What get stored in `currenttime` is the result value from `getDateInfo`, which is undefined because it has no `return` statement. The `return` within the callback function returns the server's reply to the code inside jQuery that calls the callback -- which is meaningless because that code does not expect any return value from the callback at all.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Based on the (clear) explanation I further changed the function code to `var t = $.get("time.php?a=" + Math.random() , function(data) { return data; }); return t;`, expecting the change would make the alert to work now, but still something is wrong, because now it shows `[object Object]` (in Firefox).

Comment: That won't help, because you're still expecting things to happen without waiting for the callback to be executing. I don't even know what `$.get` returns, but it certainly isn't related to the server's reply, because `$.get` _returns before the server has replied_. You _can't_ get the reply to appear _anywhere_ except _in the callback_ or _in code that is called by the callback_.

Comment: Confirmed! The `$get` function returns a reference to the `XMLHttpRequest` object. I changed the alert part again, this time to `setTimeout("alert(currenttime.responseText);",3000);` and could get the date to be displayed by the alert. But as you correctly point, that responseText arrives *after* the assignment line is executed - but as we are storing a reference to the object, at the time the alert is fired, the request has completed and it has acquired a responseText: http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/P2JxJ/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return data to an anonymous function. you must set current time within the callback of the $.get action.

```
var currentTime;
$.get("time.php?a=" + Math.random() , 
      function(data) { // this will execute when the server request is complete & successful.
          currentTime = data;
          alert(currentTime);
    });
```